# Android: Media file Path

Tags: android

I am trying to get the available media on my internal storage.

I have created a folder "teststorage" in the actual phone. I pushed song by DDMS push.

Question: What is the file path I have to mention in the Java file?.

Sample Code :

```
final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/mnt/shell/emulated/O/teststorage");
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList() 
 {
       File musicFolder = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
       if (musicFolder.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) 
       {
          for (File file : musicFolder.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) 
          {
             HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
             song.put("songTitle",file.getName().substring(0,(file.getName().length() - 4)));
             song.put("songPath", file.getPath());
             // Adding each song to SongList
             songsList.add(song);
           }
        }
     // return songs list array
        return songsList;
 }
```

This is the path I can see in the DDMS File Explorer, but in the same case I see the path as

```
"/storage/emulated/O/teststorage"
```

in the File Explorer inside the phone.

Now which one to mention in the code to get list. I tried both but its not listing any song.

What wrong I am doing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below

```
File file= new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/emulated/O/teststorage");
```

Also use `File.seperator` instead of `/`

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Check the topic under Accessing files on external storage

Comment: In my case File musicFolder= new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/teststorage"); worked as "android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()" was returning the path till "/storage/emulated/O" So added the rest. Thanks

Comment: @Jeet `android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` gives path of sdcard. if you have teststorage under it it will work. But you told you have it under `emulated/O/teststorage` so accroding to that i provided the solution. But the method is the same. Use `getExternalStorageDirectory()` get he path of external storage. then you can get the path of files undder it